# Address format checkout page issue in Magento 2.2.3

Tags: magento2, checkout, address, format

On the checkout page the address format is not assumed. Customer address format defined in the backend is ignored.

This is the format defined in backend

> {{depend prefix}}{{var prefix}} {{/depend}}{{var firstname}} {{depend middlename}}{{var middlename}} {{/depend}}{{var lastname}}{{depend suffix}} {{var suffix}}{{/depend}}{{depend firstname}}
> {{/depend}}
>       {{depend company}}{{var company}}
> {{/depend}}
>       {{if street1}}{{var street1}}
> {{/if}}
>
> {{depend street2}}{{var street2}}
> {{/depend}}
>       {{depend street3}}{{var street3}}
> {{/depend}}
>       {{depend street4}}{{var street4}}
> {{/depend}}
>       {{if postcode}}{{var postcode}}{{/if}} {{if city}}{{var city}},  {{/if}}{{if region}}{{var region}}{{/if}}
>       {{var country}}
>       {{depend vat_id}}
> UID-Nummer: {{var vat_id}}{{/depend}}

Magento2 V 2.2.3 - default checkout page

Comment: what config setting did you change? there are 3

Comment: i've changed all settings (text, one line, html & pdf)

Comment: did you check the correct store-scope? and have you clean the config cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to overwrite the templates

`vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/billing-address/details.html`

`vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-address/address-renderer/default.html`